# How to unlock a java wrapper script in informix

Tags: java, sql, database, informix

So I have this process that runs on my (inherited) informix database. For some reason the process is failing at a certain location. I cant see what the error code is, but the statement before states opening informix database, executing sql statements, then the heartbeat tries to get a respond but it doesnt and it keeps trying to get a heartbeat response.

process I run
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar bin/LaborProInterface.jar --options "flash" --location

Comment: It sounds like you didn't also inherit source code?  Java is a compiled language and the "jar" file you run has one or more individual files inside of it.  You can see what is inside by running `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jar -tvf bin/LaborProInterface.jar`  This will not extract anything - just let you know what is inside.  Likely there are many ".class" files - this is the compiled source code.  While there are tools to decompile the .class files they are not perfect so if you can find source code you'd be much better off.  The source files will end in .java

Comment: I see some of the files with the .jar ending. How do i open that to see the code inside?

Comment: Use the "jar" command like in my first comment.  The arguments are very similar to the Unix "tar" command.